# Need to achieve it

Tags: html, css

Hi ia m trying to make a old template my self i have done uptop the below code i didnt understand how to achieve the middle body part.Please see the image to understand what i need to achieve.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>static3</title>
<style type="text/css">
#content {
 float: right;
 width: 630px;
 padding: 30px 30px 0 0;
}
.headerTop {
 
 height:150px;
 width:80%;
 background-position:center;
 align-self:center;
 background-color: #444466;
 border-top-right-radius: 2em;
 border-top-left-radius: 2em;
 text-align:center;

 }
 
 logo{
  font-size:100px;
 font-style: italic;
 line-height: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 
 
 }
 
 
.footerBottom {
 background-color: #664444;
 width:80%;
 height:30px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
 text-align:center;
 
 }
 .bodyHome{
  height:400px;
  width:80%;
    
 }
  
</style>
</head>
<center><header class="headerTop"><logo>My Website<logo></headerTop></center>
<body>

<center><footer class="footerBottom">Footbar Inc</footer></center>
</body>

</html>
```

http://postimg.org/image/qt891yde7/

See the image i need to achieve like that.Thanks for your help...

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward. Just add a main container with 2 DIVs at set widths. (this isn't a coding service, we can help you with something you've tried, but we're not doing it for you.) .. P.S., the `<center>` tag is depreciated, you shouldn't use it anymore.

Comment: @GavinThomas You can still use `<center>`? But it's not recommended to use it to force the template to stay in the middle. Use `margin: 0px auto` instead.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't use it - but it's not viable for future versions of browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center `This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.`

Comment: You have to fix that HTML too; you open a `header` tag and close with a `headerTop` tag. Also, you open a `logo` tag, and instead of closing, you open it again. Change that to `</logo>`.